# How to check if there are block in getChildHtml in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, xml, phtml

In my code, there are many blocks that will be rendered but is there a product page that isn't rendering because there are no custom options.

> How can I check if it'll return some blocks in my **phtml**?

```
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('', true);?>
```

Today I'm using like that:

```
$_getChildHtml = $block->getChildHtml('', true);
$_hasOptionsPersonalize = strpos($_getChildHtml, 'class="field"') ? true : false;
```

Comment: Sorry donot understand ur last point

Comment: I've updated my question @AmitBera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you should build your child blocks that only render any html if they have to.

In this case, you can just check if the getChildHtml does not return a null string

```
<?php if ($childHtml = $block->getChildHtml('', true)): ?>
    <div><?= $childHtml ?></div>
<?php endif; >
```

In your child block you could have an if condition for example `if field != null`

Comment: it return empty array